# error in loading package arulesViz in windows 8

Tags: r

when I try to load package arulesViz I am getting following error.

```
> library('arulesViz')
    Loading required package: grid
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arulesViz’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
     there is no package called ‘iterators’

>library('iterators')
Error in library("iterators") : there is no package called ‘iterators’
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 0):

install.packages("arulesViz", dependencies = TRUE)
This wil help resolve the error